# Multi-level sorting or orderBy in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4

I am working on mongoDB with Laravel using [jenssegers](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB) . and i am trying to get 
documents on sorting based on layout.price.

Is this possible in mongodb with laravel. ?

I am using limit and skip for pagination , so i have to get orderBy or sort direct from Database.

```
[{
  "title": "I am first document",
  "design": "mango",
  "description": "Loremipsum",
  "dimension": [
    {
      "id": "542549383d1784901000002c"
    }
  ],
  "layout": [

    {
      "id": "542411813d17849810000029",
      "price": NumberInt(69000)
    }, {
      "id": "542411813d17849810000030",
      "price": NumberInt(2000)
    }

  ],
  "images": [
    "uploads/sofa/QRSTU695a6_0.png"
  ],
  "product_type": NumberInt(1),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2014-10-08T08:47:26.0Z"),
  "created_at": ISODate("2014-09-29T11:13:52.0Z")
},
{
  "title": "I am second document",
  "design": "mango2",
  "description": "Loremipsum",
  "dimension": [
    {
      "id": "542549383d1784901000002d"
    }
  ],
  "layout": [

    {
      "id": "542411813d17849810000031",
      "price": NumberInt(80000)
    }, {
      "id": "542411813d17849810000032",
      "price": NumberInt(27000)
    }

  ],
  "images": [
    "uploads/sofa/QRSTU695a6_0.png"
  ],
  "product_type": NumberInt(1),
  "updated_at": ISODate("2014-10-08T08:47:26.0Z"),
  "created_at": ISODate("2014-09-29T11:13:52.0Z")
}]
```

Comment: Since you have multiple `layout.price` fields per document by what do you want to sort? Sum, min, max or do you want to get back a single document per element of `layout`?

Comment: @trudbert : I want to get all document based on lowest to highest layout.price .

Comment: Yes but you have multiple prices per document so taken the two documents above: do you want a get two documents sorted on some sort of accumulated price (e.g. I could read your comment "as sort by difference between highest and lowest per document") or do you want to get four, one for each price and have them sorted?

Comment: @Trudbert :I have around 500 documents, i want this sorting on all of this documents . Thnks

Comment: The number of documents isn't the problem. The number of price fields per document is. For example your document with  `"title": "I am first document"` has two `layout.price` fields with values 69000 and 2000. The quesion is do you want to get one result per price so in the sorted results one copy of document with price 2000 and one with 69000 (i.e. the same document at different spots with different prices) or do you want to sort by the avererage/sum/difference price per document?